# MarkLogic 9.0.5 and DHF 3.0 fail to load mlcp module on mlDeploy

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a clean marklogic server installation together with gradle DHF(Data Hub Framework) 3.0 project.
In the build.gradle, I have a custom task that triggers an input flow and loads the files by using MLCP. 
The code looks like the following.

```
task importEntity(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.MlcpTask) {
classpath = configurations.mlcp
command = "IMPORT"
...
...
transform_module = "/com.marklogic.hub/mlcp-flow-transform.xqy"
transform_namespace = "http://marklogic.com/data-hub/mlcp-flow-transform"
... }
```

When the command is run, the execution fails due to a non-existing module (/com.marklogic.hub/mlcp-flow-transform.xqy) in MarkLogic modules database.

If I check modules database, I see that the only custom modules were uploaded but not a single dependency from MarkLogic on mlDeploy.

I am wondering, what could have gone wrong.

Thank in advance.

Best,
Igor

Comment: When you say "custom modules were uploaded", does that mean that "/com.marklogic.hub/mlcp-flow-transform.xqy" is in your modules or not in your modules database? Also not sure what you mean by "but not a single dependency".

Comment: It turns out that data-hub-framework modules are already in MarkLogic Modules directory and they do not need to be imported into the modules database.

    import module namespace es = "http://marklogic.com/entity-services" at "/MarkLogic/entity-services/entity-services.xqy";

Which is equivalent to system path as below.

    C:\Program Files\MarkLogic\Modules\MarkLogic

Apologize for the unclear questions and thank you for finding time to help!

Comment: @igordr Hi, did the gradle mlcp task work for you in the end? I also got the error about missing the mlcp-flow-transform.xqy module which is not in my data-hub-MODULES database. Based on your hint, I changed the module address to "/MarkLogic/data-hub-framework/transforms/mlcp-flow-transform.xqy" which led to another error "XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) let $_must_run_in_query_mode as xs:unsignedLong := xdmp:request-timestamp() -- Invalid coercion: () as xs:unsignedLong"

Comment: @FanLi That is a problem with mlcp within ML modules. I have the same issue and intend to work on it. Please update if you find the solution earlier.

Comment: @igordr The approach discussed here solved the problem for me: https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/issues/1032